# show facebook php script error messages

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way to let php error messages show up in a facebook canvas app for my own debugging purposes, or does facebook truncate errors before sending output to the browser?

A related question is whether or not php error messages normally appear in the browser window in the first place.

Comment: You should be checking your error log instead.

Comment: is this the only way to do it?  i don't have experience with php outside of this facebook stuff I've started, but in general, don't php scripts usually output error messages to the browser?

Comment: it is bad practice to output errors this way.  Errors often contain data which could be used by an attacker.  This especially true when your stack trace contains usernames, passwords, security keys, etc.

Comment: when you say bad practice, you imply that this can be turned on and off?  I'm assuming it's all done in php.ini?

Comment: that is correct.  It can also be set within your code.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  and http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing i'd recommend you is to use "[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)" for firefox, it helps a lot to debug
while you're working on your application. Another thing is the built-in facebook API Exception (PHP SDK) Try-Catch:

```
try
{
    // Your Graph API Calls Ex: $userInfo = $facebook->api("/me","GET");   
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
// After you're done debugging, comment out the below lines
       $result = $e->getResult();
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($result);
       echo "</pre>";
}
```

If you don't know what is Exception, then check out this link: [PHP Exception Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp)

Also this might help you as well: [PHP Error Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp) or [set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler)